# the set of matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ satisfies following properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

consider a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R^{2\times2}}$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and let $A$ has the following properties

$\bullet$ $A$ is not invertible

$\bullet$ $A$ is symmetric

$\bullet$ all the entries of $A$ is positive

$\bullet$ $A$ has a positive eigenvalue $\lambda=p>0$

Find the set of all matrices $A$ as a function of $p$

**My attempt**

$\bullet$ $A$ is not invertible $\implies ad=bc$

$\bullet$ $A$ is symmetric $\implies b=c$

$$(A-\lambda I)v=0\\
\begin{bmatrix}
a-\lambda & b \\
c & d-\lambda 
\end{bmatrix}v=0\\
(a-\lambda)(d-\lambda )-bc=0\\
\lambda^2-\lambda (a+d)+ad-cb=0\quad,\text{and}\quad ad=bc\\
\lambda^2-\lambda (a+d)=0$$

We know the determinant is the product of eigenvalue. Since it is singular, one of its eigenvalue must be zero, and the other is $p=a+d$

So the set of all matrices is as long as $p=a+d$

**Second way**

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}
ac & bc \\
ca & da 
\end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}
0 & ad-bc \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}
c & d \\
0 & ad-bc 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $c$ will be that positive eigenvalue, and $ad=bc=p^2$ then proceeded to obtain

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & p \\
p & \frac{p^2}{a} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

What's wrong with this second way? I think it's row operation change the eigenvalue? I am not too sure.

Comment: What's your question? Or should it be a wiki?

Comment: Very good so far. What's your question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure if this is correct, is this looks right?

Comment: Just a note: rather than perform all of that algebra, you could use that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues (as you noted) and the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues to know that $a+d=p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You we have done is fine. It lacks the final answer to the question, which is:$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&\sqrt{a(p-a)}\\\sqrt{a(p-a)}&p-a\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,a\in(0,p)\right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I then tried differently, going with reducing the matrix into a triangular form, then it seems to get a different answer. Is that never trying to find the eigenvalue by reducing the matrix into triangular form?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that approach. Without seeing the details, I can't say what went wrong. But note that what you got were the matrices $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ which are symmetric, with $0$ determinant and such that $a+d=p(\iff d=p-a)$. That is precisely my answer.

Comment: I think it should be $a\in [0,p]$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your reply. I've just edited another part.

Comment: @Joe If positive here means greater than or equal to $0$, yes. But I assumed that it meant greater than $0$.

Comment: ah, I completely missed that condition.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos would you please check out my **Second way**

Comment: Why would $c$ be the positive eigenvalue? Why not $ad-bc$? Besides, do you have something against my solution?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't have any issue with your solution, but I cannot tell exactly where **method 2** went wrong. The $c$ be eigenvalues simply turns matrix into a triangular form, so that the diagonal is the eigenvalues, $ad-bc$ is another eigenvalue $0$

Comment: In the first step of your sequence of matrices, you multiply the first line by $c$ and the second line by $a$. That changes the eigenvalues. If a matrix is, say, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\3&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, its eigenvalues are $2$ and $0$. Now, if you multiply the first line by $3$ and the second line by $2$, you get $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}6&0\\6&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, its eigenvalues are $6$ and $0$, not $2$ and $0$.